# How to detect that socket is not listening for udp

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am trying to send data over udp. It works, however I don't get any errors even if destination socket is not exist. Is there any way to detect that socket is not listening?

I am using this code. Nothing is listening on port 8081, but I don't get errors at all. In contrast, if i do the same from python I get error message "Connection refused".

```
use tokio::net::UdpSocket;
use std::error::Error;
use std::io;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let socket = UdpSocket::bind("127.0.0.1:8080").await?;

    let dst = "127.0.0.1:8081".parse()?;

    loop {
        socket.writable().await?;

        match socket.try_send_to(&b"hello world"[..], dst) {
            Ok(sent) => {
                println!("sent {} bytes", sent);
            }
            Err(ref e) if e.kind() == io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock => {
                // Writable false positive.
                println!("{e}");
            }
            Err(e) => return Err(e.into()),
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Update: updated code according for the Steffen's comment below. Still no errors on sending udp message to non listening port.

Comment: *if i do the same from python I get error message "Connection refused"* - I doubt this. If you do a single `send` in Python to a UDP target where no one is bound too, you should not get an error. You should at most get an error on the second `send`, since then the ICMP unreachable is processed and flagged as a problem on the socket.  If you think otherwise please show the actual Python code you have used.

Comment: With code above I tried to send more than 100 messages and never got any errors on send_to?!

Comment: Again, please provide the matching python code. I don't get any errors in python if I structure the code like you do - using sendto and an unconnected socket. I only get errors with a connected socket using send.

Comment: Ahh, I got what you mean... In python I did bind to the socket and then sendall. This is why it worked! So, in my case for Rust I need to do the same. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDP has no real connection like TCP does, i.e. with an initial connection establishment before any data get send. Thus in order to detect if there is some UDP listener at the destination one need to send a packet there and then check if the packet got received.

UDP has a mechanism for this: if the receiving system gets a UDP packet for an IP,port without a listener it will send an ICMP unreachable back (for IPv4, similar message for IPv6). Assuming that this ICMP packet actually reaches the original sender (i.e. no firewalls blocking it) then the socket will be marked with this error and the error will be delivered on the next socket operation, like another send.

But, this is only true if the socket is connected, i.e. `socket.connect("127.0.0.1:8081")` called in your example (and `socket.try_send` used instead of `socket.try_send_to`).  For unconnected sockets (as in your case) the error will not be delivered since it does not match a specific connection (since there is no connection).

> if i do the same from python I get error message "Connection refused"

If you use an unconnected socket in Python you also don't get the error. If you use a connected socket you get the error. So likely your python code was not doing "the same" what your rust code did.

> (from comment) In python I did bind to the socket and then sendall.

`sendall` has no argument for a destination, so it requires a connected socket. Hence the error was delivered to the connected socket.